# Table of contents empty with beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

My table of contents in beamer is empty, I got 4 sections and 3 subsections, but no one of them appears in my table of contents. Here is my code :

```
\documentclass[smaller,t]{beamer}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\frenchbsetup{option1=false,option2=true,option3=false}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\includemovie}[4]        {\includemedia[width=#1,height=#2,activate=pageopen,addresource=#3,flashvars={src=#3&loop=true&controlBarAutoHide=false}]{#4}{StrobeMediaPlayback.swf}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{isomath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
{
\usetheme[width=1.5cm]{Berkeley}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\raggedright\insertcaption\par}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}  
}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{} 
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame} % premier transparent 
\frametitle{Plan de présentation}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\section{Problématique}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Contexte industriel}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have a `{....}` pair around most of your `beamer` related settings. And the font color is white and hard to detect. Correct the `\frenchbsetup` command too, please

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
{
\usetheme[width=1.5cm]{Berkeley}
\usecolortheme{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\raggedright\insertcaption\par}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}  
}
```

is effectively useless all settings occur within a `{...}` group, i.e. the settings do not survive after the end of the group.

Omitting the `{...}` pair, the `\tableofcontents` appears in the sidebar, however, the colortheme is very inconvenient for this!

```
\documentclass[smaller,t]{beamer}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
%\frenchbsetup{option1=false,option2=true,option3=false}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{isomath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}

\newcommand{\includemovie}[4]        {\includemedia[width=#1,height=#2,activate=pageopen,addresource=#3,flashvars={src=#3&loop=true&controlBarAutoHide=false}]{#4}{StrobeMediaPlayback.swf}}

\usetheme[width=1.5cm]{Berkeley}
\usecolortheme{crane}
%\usecolortheme{beaver}% hard to see!
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\raggedright\insertcaption\par}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}  

\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{} 
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Plan de présentation} % premier transparent 
%\frametitle{Plan de présentation}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
\section{Problématique}
\begin{frame}{Contexte industriel}
\end{frame}
\section{Et maintenant}
\begin{frame}{Des baguettes}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{Nl-baguettes2.jpg}
\captionof{figure}{Nom nom nom}
\end{center}
Source: \url{CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=422101}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have corrected this first part, but I still have an empty table of contents with only the title "Plan de présentation"

Comment: @Abdallah: Did you compile (at least) twice?

Comment: Yes, very strange I am compiling with xelatex

Comment: @Abdallah: I've recompiled with `xelatex` (I have to remove `inputenc` of course), but I still get the ToC

Comment: Please see the [link](https://s31.postimg.org/sxwzjv4yj/Screen_Shot_2016_07_11_at_7_11_24_PM.png)

Comment: @Abdallah: Thank you for the mail, didn't notice your  comment. Actually, the ToC is there, at the left navigation bar!